# Is is possible to set StartTime/EndTime dynamically?

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj

I'm new to Quickfix/J.

Could I set or overwrite the StartTime/EndTime dynamically or programmably so that the value of StartTime will be the exact time when I start the program?

Or I need to modify the source codes to achieve that?

Thanks you

Comment: Even though setting these values programmatically is possible, you should be aware that these values have to match the values configured on the counter-party you are connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

After you create your `SessionSettings` object, you can overwrite the values for start and end time.

```
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(inputStream);
settings.setString(Session.SETTING_START_TIME, startTime);
settings.setString(Session.SETTING_END_TIME, endTime);
```

The times are the format of HH:MM:SS [timezone]. The time zone is optional. The TimeZone setting will be used, if set, or UTC will be used by default. The timezone string should be one that the Java TimeZone class can resolve. For example, "15:00:00 US/Central". See theq QuickFIX/J documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post *might* answer your question:
[Stackoverflow set starttime endtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247829/quickfix-set-starttime-endtime)

I haven't used Quickfix before, so I'm not certain if this helps.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ok @Takendarkk. That makes sense. How would this normally be handled? I'm kind of new to posting on stackoverflow. It seems this is a question already asked, is there a  procedure for handling already asked questions?

Comment: Well you did just what you should, refer the question asker to that particular question. If it is an _exact_ or _nearly exact_ question you can flag this question as a duplicate. The reason you would want to post this as a comment and not an answer is to avoid people downvoting you as it would decrease you reputation points.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I think your link isn't helpful.